# ios shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Hi my application consist of a UIViewController which is a child of a UINavigationController which is a child of a UITabbarController. My issue is only the UITabbarController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation function is being called.

The UIViewController and UINavigationController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation functions are not being called

Any ideas.

Comment: All Good. I just realised i need to do the following

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   return [self.visibleViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}